# Use A instead of/ rather than B

Tags: grammar, word-choice, vocabulary

I wish to know if I should use Instead of or Rather Than in this sentence:

> Sometimes, people use pencils *instead of*/ *rather than* pens.

I'd rather use "Rather than" (since it is used for preference), but I'm not so sure. Could you help me?

Comment: I believe [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164010/when-to-use-rather-than-versus-instead-of) answers your question.

Comment: "Rather" indicates a preference, but "instead" can be because of impossibility. "I would **rather** cycle to work than go by train but it is too far to cycle regularly. But when the trains are cancelled, I ride a bike to work **instead**."

Comment: It is often helpful for advanced learners to understand the derivation of words too. “Instead of” literally means “in place of”: https://www.etymonline.com/word/instead#etymonline_v_9350